# How to store the output of command "which" in a variable in a bash script?

Tags: bash, macos, shell

**Environment:**

Mac OS Catalina 10.15

GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19)

**Problem:**

I have a bash script.

I try to test if MacPOrt is installed.

When I run the command "port -v", it open Macport terminal and the rest of my script is broken.

So I try another approach with the command "which port".
It gives the output "port not found" but I don't succeed to store it in a variable. My variable is empty.

You can see here below the source code of my bash script executing 2 commands:

1. The first one give an empty value.
2. The second one give a value if Macport is not installed. But if it is installed, it open the Macport terminal and break my code.

> 

```
OUTPUT=$(which port 2>&1)

echo "OUTPUT is $OUTPUT"

if echo "$OUTPUT" | grep -q "port not found"; then

    echo "MacPort is NOT installed"

else

    echo "MacPort is installed"

fi

echo "======================================================================"

OUTPUT=$(port -v 2>&1)

echo "OUTPUT is $OUTPUT"

if echo "$OUTPUT" | grep -q "command not found"; then

    echo "MacPort is NOT installed"

else

    echo "MacPort is installed"

fi
```

> 

Here is the output:

```
OUTPUT is 
MacPort is installed
======================================================================
OUTPUT is test.sh: line 11: port: command not found
MacPort is NOT installed
```

So it seems 'which' command doesn't behave like other commands. How can I store the output of 'which' command?
If it is not possible, I am agree to accept any other trick to test of Macport is installed.

Comment: Cannot reproduce (although not on MacOS here). `OUTPUT=$(which port 2>&1)` followed by `echo $OUTPUT` gives me `which: no port in ($PATH)`. Note "no port in", not "port not found". In any case, `OUTPUT` is not empty for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script has bugs:

```
OUTPUT=$(which port 2>&1)

echo "OUTPUT is $OUTPUT"

if echo "$OUTPUT" | grep -q "port not found"; then
    echo "MacPort is NOT installed"
else
    echo "MacPort is installed"
fi
```

You are checking for `port not command`. But `which` command doesn't actually output anything if `port` isn't found (whether `which` outputs anything differs on different systems). This is seen in your output (`OUTPUT` is empty).

In any case, you can't rely on `which` as it may not output anything
in some versions and even its return code isn't reliable on some old platforms.

A better approach is to use [`command` or `type` built-ins](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#SHELL_BUILTIN_COMMANDS) of bash (This also avoids calling an external command like `which`):

```
if type port &>/dev/null; then
    echo "MacPort is installed"
else
    echo "MacPort is NOT installed"
fi
```

---

```
if command -v port &>/dev/null; then
    echo "MacPort is installed"
else
    echo "MacPort is NOT installed"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

If what you're really looking for is just to check if the `port` command is available, the right way to do it in bash would be:

```
if ! command -v port > /dev/null; then
  echo "MacPort is not installed"
  exit 1
fi
```